# При помощи каких технологий создаются "визуальные редакторы" типа WordPress?

Tags: javascript, html, форматирование

Интересуют следующие вопросы:

1. Как делаются визуальные редакторы (или как их правильно называть?) на подобии этого (WordPress)?
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Как хранится разметка? Много раз слышал, что хранить HTML-разметку в БД - это плохо. Так ли это? И что делать, если это так? Как хранить?
3. Наиболее интересным для меня является то, что все видно именно так, как это будет на странице в конечном итоге. Нет такого как, например, на этом же SO. Здесь мы можем окружить слово **звездочками** и оно окажется жирным после того, как сообщение будет запостчено. Но прямо сейчас, набирая этот текст, я не вижу слово жирным. Я вижу его окруженным звездочками.

**Ответы на ваши возможные вопросы:**

- Да, я посмотрел код страницы. Там есть `iframe`, ссылающийся на `javascript`. Как это работает - вопрос.
- В гуглоподобных искать пробовал, но выдача совсем не та, что я ожидаю. Вполне вероятно, из-за того, что я неправильно формулирую вопрос.
- Да, у меня есть свои мысли на этот счет. И самая основная - это `<div contenteditable>`. Но, как не пытайся, максимум, что это может дать - такую же форму, как и на SO. Плюс, не знаю, как потом отправить это формой. Неужели придется копировать JS'ом содержимое `<div>`'а в `<input type="hidden">`, попутно заменяя `**` на `<strong>`, а `__` на `<em>`?

Короче говоря, прошу прощения, если этот вопрос - дубликат, ибо не могу найти нужного мне ответа.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Визуальные редакторы делаются на js. Схема достаточно проста — есть скрытый блок textarea в которой хранится результирующий html код, который после нажатия на кнопку сохранить например отправляется на сервер гре проверяется, экранируется и сохраняется в базу. Есть блок c тегом contenteditable. Контент при изменении сохраняется в textarea. Есть кнопки управления которые добавляют новые теги или оборачивают выделенный текст (это делается с помощью регурярок, функций отслеживания выбранного текста и т.д.). Есть вплывающие окна в которых вводятся дополнительные параметры и т.д.

2) Хранить HTML разметку в DB это нормальная практика, а как без этого. Просто нужно тщательно всё экранировать, защищать от SQL injection и других.

3) Вариант с использованием блока с тегом contenteditable как раз то что Вам нужно там всё выглядит так же как и будет выглядеть — главное следить что бы стили нужные были подключены.

Если нужны ещё подробности задавайте вопросы или пробуйте — так проще понять как и что происходит.

**В помощь информация:**

- [Параметр contenteditable](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/contenteditable)
- [Как определить выделенный текст](https://learn.javascript.ru/range-textrange-selection#selection)

Comment: Отличный ответ, спасибо. Но нужно уточнить некоторые детали. Больше всего интересует следующее: пытался я реализовать уже подобное (только часть с contenteditable), но не понимаю, как добиться того, чтобы текст "подсвечивался в реальном времени". Например, выделил я слово и нажал на кнопку "B" (чтобы сделать жирным). Что должно происходить дальше? Ведь если просто обернуть JS'ом это слово, то оно так и будет в div'е: дословно `<b>слово</b>`, а не реально выделенное жирным. Или я не прав?

Comment: Нет Вы не правы. Если вы найдёте «слово» в блоке contenteditable и замените его на «<b>слово</b>», оно сразу отобразится как Вы хотите — сразу будет показано жирным.

Comment: Оба-на, неожиданный поворот. Значит я делал что-то неправильно. Я сейчас поэкспериментирую, и если все так, как вы говорите, то ответ ваш.

Comment: Ну в принципе да, работает. Значит мыслил я правильно. Спасибо за ответ :)